# How to compare an item within a list of list in python

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python and just learning things as I do my project and here I have a list of lists which I need to compare between the second and last column and get the output for the one which has the largest distance. Moreover, I am replicating a list. If someone could help me to do it within a single list of lists in ag it could be really helpful.
Thanks in advance

if this is an INPUT then the output should be,

```
ag = [['chr12','XX',1,5,4],
     ['chr12','XX',2,5,3],
     ['chr13','ZZ',6,10,4],
     ['chr13','ZZ',8,9,1],
     ['ch14','YY',12,15,3],['ch14','YY',12,15,3]]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

     ['chr12','XX',1,5,4]
     ['chr13','ZZ',6,10,4]
     ['ch14','YY',12,15,3]

#However I tried of replicating the list like
#INPUT
ag = 
 [['chr12','XX',1,5,4],
 ['chr12','XX',2,5,3],
 ['chr13','ZZ',6,10,4],
 ['chr13','ZZ',8,9,1],
 ['ch14','YY',12,15,3],
 ['ch14','YY',12,15,3]]
 bg = 
 [['chr12','XX',1,5,4],
 ['chr12','XX',2,5,3],
 ['chr13','ZZ',6,10,4],
 ['chr13','ZZ',8,9,1],
 ['ch14','YY',12,15,3],
 ['ch14','YY',12,15,3]]


#The code which I tried was

c= []
for i in ag:
 for j in bg:
    if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and i[4]>j[4]:
        c.append(i)


the output which i get is
[['chr12', 'XX', 1, 5, 4], ['chr13', 'ZZ', 6, 10, 4]]
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, specifically add "what-did-you-expect" part, since you've already added what you've got.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to achieve? Maybe even in pseudo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: To compare items in an iterable (e.g. list) of lists, use the keyword agument `key` of the max/min function. It takes a function or lambda expression and compares the given values by the result of the `key` function when given each value.

---

Assuming that what you really want is to reduce a list of lists so that the entries' second elements are unique and that you want the last elements to determin which entry to keep in case of redundant 2nd values:

If there is any problem regarding iteration, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) has the answer. In this case, we just need the `groupby` method and standard Python's [max](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/max) method with the keyword argument `key`.

```
from itertools import groupby

def filter(matrix):
    filtered = [] # create a result list to hold the rows (lists) we want
    for key, rows in groupby(matrix, lambda row: row[1]): # get the rows grouped by their 2nd element and iterate over that
        filtered.append(max(rows, key=lambda row: row[-1])) # add the line that among its group has the largest last value to our result
    return filtered # return the result
```

We could squeeze this into a single generator expression or list comprehension but for a beginner, the above code should be complex enought.

Please be sure to follow Stack Overflow's [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions to prevent low ratings and ensure prompt and high quality answers.

Comment: @NishaHemandhar: I'm not here to fix code but to improve programming. Just make sure you check out itertools whenever you face an iteration problem and it was worth my time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your list `ag` and `bg` are completely duplicating, so I give this example for your issue. Hope it help.

```py
>>>ag = [['chr12','XX',1,5,4],['chr12','XX',2,5,3],['chr13','ZZ',6,10,4],['chr13','ZZ',8,9,1],['ch14','YY',12,15,3]]
>>>bg = [['chr12','XX',1,5,4],['chr12','XX',2,5,3],['chr13','ZZ',6,10,4],['chr13','ZZ',8,9,1]]
>>>[i for i in ag + bg if i not in ag or i not in bg]
[['ch14', 'YY', 12, 15, 3]]
```

Comment: I have the same data in both list. Thanks for your help