# Keeping the lowest value of duplicates across multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = dict(name=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
            objective=[20.0, 20.0, 25.0, 40.0, 40.5, 41.0, 60.0, 60.0],
            price=[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 0.5, 1.0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
```

I can then find the unique combinations of all these as follows:

```
df.groupby(['name','objective', 'price']).size()
```

which looks like this:

```
name  objective  price
a     20.0       0.5      1
                 1.0      1
      25.0       1.5      1
b     40.0       1.0      1
      40.5       1.2      1
      41.0       1.4      1
c     60.0       0.5      1
                 1.0      1
```

When there are multiple `price` values for a given `name` and `objective`, I want to keep the lower `price` value *only*, i.e.

```
name  objective  price
a     20.0       0.5      1
      25.0       1.5      1
b     40.0       1.0      1
      40.5       1.2      1
      41.0       1.4      1
c     60.0       0.5      1
```

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: why was `25.0       1.5      1` retained for `a` name?

Comment: Isn't that the exact same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56848352/7967942) question (except `min` instead of `max`)? If not, can you clairfy the difference?

Answer (score 2):

You can do another `groupby` and `first`:

```
(df.groupby(['name','objective', 'price']).size()
   .reset_index()
   .groupby(['name', 'objective'])
   .first()
)
```

Output:

```
                price  0
name objective          
a    20.0         0.5  1
     25.0         1.5  1
b    40.0         1.0  1
     40.5         1.2  1
     41.0         1.4  1
c    60.0         0.5  1
```

Answer (score 2):

What I will do

```
df.sort_values('price').drop_duplicates(['name','objective'],keep='last').assign(cnt=1)
Out[421]: 
  name  objective  price  cnt
0    a       20.0    0.5    1
2    a       25.0    1.5    1
3    b       40.0    1.0    1
4    b       40.5    1.2    1
5    b       41.0    1.4    1
6    c       60.0    0.5    1
```

Comment: Assuming it is sorted on `'price'`.

Comment: @wwii yep , :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use groupby and minimum

```py
df = df.groupby(['name','objective']).min()
```

Comment: Thanks.. can you specify the column name *price* in the `min` function?

Comment: if you add `.reset_index()` right after that, by default the column name is `price`